# NameError: name 'Option' is not defined

Tags: python

I'm writing a discord bot via py-cord and I get NameError: name 'Option' is not defined.
Using pre-release version. Extensions are added.

Code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = discord.Bot()

@bot.slash_command(guild_ids=[...])
async def hello(
    ctx: discord.ApplicationContext,
    name: Option(str, "Enter your name"),
    age: Option(int, "Enter your age", min_value=1, max_value=99, default=18)
    # passing the default value makes an argument optional
    # you also can create optional argument using:
    # age: Option(int, "Enter your age") = 18
):
    await ctx.respond(f"Hello! Your name is {name} and you are {age} years old.")

bot.run('real token is here')
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What's not clear from the error? You use an identifier `Option` which is never defined. What did you *mean* it to be?

Comment: try `from discord import Option`

Comment: @matszwecja In this case, it would make more sense to simply do `discord.Option`... (assuming `discord` does have an `Option` attribute and that's what the OP is looking for. More details are needed for this question)

Comment: @matszwecja Thanks, that helped!

P.S.: Not sure how to mark comment here as answer. Repost the answer please, so I can mark it as correct

Comment: @Tomerikoo This is the example from py-cord library, which for some reason gave me an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple fix for this is instead of Option, just do

```py
    name: discord.Option(str, "Enter your name"),
    age: discord.Option(int, "Enter your age", min_value=1, max_value=99, default=18)
```

or:

```py
from discord import Option
```

and it'll be fixed! Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! For some reason it was not included in docs.

[Link to the docs part, where I found this example](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/api.html?highlight=options#discord.SlashCommand.options)

Comment: @BurAndBY most decent code editors will suggest you an auto-import if some variable is available in one of the installed modules. It is quite common for imports to be omitted.